# Retreiving Data from Firebase Into Dropdown boxes on a Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, firebase-realtime-database

Below is code snippet of .JSON file from firebase database.

```
"question papers" : {
    "APPLE" : {
      "location" : "mp",
      "stream" : {
        "btech" : {
          "CSE" : {
            "1st sem" : {
              "2017" : "google.com"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "SIETK" : {
      "location" : "ap",
      "stream" : {
        "MBA" : {
          "MBA" : {
            "1st sem" : {
              "2015" : "google.com"
            }
          }
        },
```

I have create dropdown boxes one by one and get data to that boxes from firebase as in question papers section .JSON file. 
1st box- College name and location,
2nd Box- Stream,
3rd Box-Department and so on. 
How should I go about this problem?` I tried the following but it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userDataref=firebase.database().ref('/question papers/')
userDataref.once("value").then(function(snapshot){
    var key=snapshot.key;
    alert(snapshot.value());
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will be useful to you

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username) || 'Anonymous';
  // ...
});
```